# Proof involving continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, solution-verification

[image]

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Im}{Im}$
We've just started to learn about continuity, and this is one of the questions we were assigned.
As I am new to this topic, my confidence level in the material is quite low and I was wondering whether I am doing okay with my understanding of the material..
My proof is as follows;

> Note that f is both continuous and bounded, therefore by Weierstrass'
> Theorem, there exists $a∈ \Bbb R$ such that $f(x) ≤ f(a)$ for every $x∈\Bbb R$.
> Since $f(a)$ is the maximal point in $\Im(f)$, by definition of a
> maximum, $f(a) = \sup\Im(f) = M$.
>
> In the same way there exists $b∈R$ such that $f(b) ≤ f(x)$ for every
> $x∈R$. Since $f(b)$ is the minimal point in $\Im(f)$, by definition of
> a minimum, $f(b) = \inf\Im(f) = m$ .
>
> Clearly $M,m ⊆ \Im(f)$, and since $f$ is continuous $m ≤ f(x) ≤ M$

I'm especially not sure about the last line, is there anything related to properties of continuous functions that will help me show that the image of $f$ is contained in $[m,M]$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is wrong from the start. It is false that, since $f$ is continuous and bounded, there is some $a\in\Bbb R$ such that $(\forall x\in\Bbb R):f(x)\leqslant f(a)$; take the $\arctan$ function, for instance.

Since, by definition, $M=\sup\operatorname{Im}(f)$, it is clear that $(\forall x\in\Bbb R):f(x)\leqslant M$. By a similar argument, $(\forall x\in\Bbb R):f(x)\geqslant m$. So, $\operatorname{Im}(f)\subset[m,M]$.

Now, take $a\in(m,M)$. Then, since $M=\sup\operatorname{Im}(f)>a$, there is some $x_0\in\Bbb R$ such that $f(x_0)>a$. And, since $m=\inf\operatorname{Im}(f)>a$, there is some $x_1\in\Bbb R$ such that $f(x_1)<a$. So, by the intermedite value theorem, there is some $x$ between $x_0$ and $x_1$ such that $f(x)=a$, and so $a\in\operatorname{Im}(f)$. This proves that $\operatorname{Im}(f)\supset(m,M)$.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Your explanation was very helpful. :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help.